# Java - dispose pattern

Tags: java, dispose

I want to make sure that my Objects (`Class <? extends Object>`) are properly disposed of, because other instances may hold data that are used by them. Example, a DEK/KEK pair for secret data.

Since Overriding `finalize()` is generally frowned upon, how do I make the IDE warn and **force** the developer to call `dispose()` iff the Object reference is set to null, or would be automatically set to null (example exiting a method)?

Assuming source code is under my direct control, and the IDE is Netbeans.

Comment: `Closeable` interface and RAII via try-with-resources is not enough, I guess?

Comment: Is there a way to make the IDE warn or cause compilation errors if it's not closed?

Comment: Doubt that. The objects you are talking about - is their sourcce code under your direct control? Or they are the stuff from 3rd party?

Comment: Yes, the source code is under my direct control. The IDE I'm using is Netbeans.

Comment: By the way, a reference is not "automatically set to null" when exiting a method. The reference variable simply goes out of existence.

Comment: The idiomatic way in Java is to use the `Closeable` interface (or `AutoCloseable`) and to exercise good programming habits by always using try-with-resources. I don't know if Netbeans IDE has warnings if you forget to do that, but there are third-party static analysis tools (like *findbugs*) that do.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, worth to mention that finalizers were deprecated in Java 9 in favour of the [Cleaner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html). Probably this would be the better option then the one I will describe below. Didn't tried it yet though.

Speaking about the question itself: I'd try doing it that way:

1. Assuming there is an object of type A, which implements `Closeable`.
2. Make a class S with the only method: `void execute(Consumer<A> consumer)`.
3. In the method `execute`: instantiate object of type A, pass it to consumer (`accept`) then close it.
4. In the client code - always use S, passing a lambda to it as a consumer. In lambda - you will get the instance of A and S will guarantee disposal of it.
5. Make all constructors' visibility of class A limited to only the service S (like, make them package-private and place A in the same package with S). That will prevent A to be instantiated outside of S and left unmanaged.

Comment: This is an example of the Execute Around design pattern. There is good description of it in the book [Functional Programming in Java](https://pragprog.com/book/vsjava8/functional-programming-in-java).